# how to install multiple python versions on snow leopard?

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, virtualenv, homebrew

whats is the current best practice for installing multiple versions of python on snow leopard?

- have setup python 2.7.1 via Homebrew, very easy process, all great.
- but now I need to setup python 2.5 to develop an appengine project..  Initially created a new virtualenv against system python2.5 .. but finding I have all kinds of PATH issues. Seems at this point it would be better not to use Homebrew and go with a more standard setup?

any thoughts ?

Comment: What exactly are your PATH issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snow leopard already contains python 2.5 and python 2.6, no issues there.

If you require obscure modifications to the python installations, just compile your own, and put it in some place where it won't conflict with the system python. (I suggest /opt/your-pythonx.y).

As an aside, check: "man python" on mac to see how to use the 32-bit, or 64-bit options if that turns out to be neccessary. (Sometimes it is for c modules)

Comment: I was under the impression its not best to use the bundled python versions.. they are non-standard builds/versions? ..is this no longer the case? .. hope so! would certainly be easier to use those

Comment: Really depends on your needs. That said, what makes you think that they are particularly non-standard?

Comment: ..well it does depend my needs as you say: which can necessitate multiple installs of python .. hence my question.. though its seems that potentially I could do appengine dev against the sys install of 2.5..  really, I want figure out the best way to manage multiple installs of python so I dont keep running in to these issues..

Comment: @zack: Specifically, it depends on if you depend on particular options selected when compiling the package, the particular architecture you may be after, and the particular compiler and libraries used.  Almost all of those are usually only a concern if you need to use a particular python module that has been implemented in C.

Comment: ah thanks, I'd understood the differences as being more significant :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the `python_select` utility to switch between versions (it takes care of all the paths and links).  It's easy to install with MacPorts or fink, so I would guess you can install the same utility with Homebrew.